# How to retain Long as Number only in JSON instead of String when serializing with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am converting processes map to `JSON` using `jackson 2.6.2` automatically.

```
   Map<Long,String> processes = new HashMap<>();
    processes.add(1l,"p1");
    processes.add(2l,"p2");
```

The resultant JSON is coming in `String: String` format:

```
{
        "1": "p1",
        "2": "p2"
}
```

How to retain Long Number as Number only in JSON i.e., `Number: String` like below:

```
   {
            1: "p1",
            2: "p2"
    }
```

Comment: You don't, the latter example isn't valid JSON - Jackson refuses to produce invalid JSON. If you want to produce Sagar Object Notation you will need to implement a custom dataformat.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Understood. How I missed the small thing ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys of the Javascript objects are always parsed as string.

In object literal terms, key is a property. Properties are strings in JavaScript.